# Cannot get value from multiple checkboxes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get every checked buttons over a dynamic list of objects

The solution I had seemed pretty convincing, but nothing yet...

In dire need of a solution, thanks a lot !

```
class PageDocuments(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, demarche, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
    [...] 
    self.documentsChecked = []   

    for y, document in enumerate(demarche["docNeeded"]):
        cvar = StringVar()
        cvar.set("off")
        cb = tk.Checkbutton(self, variable=cvar, text=document,onvalue=document, offvalue='off')
        relyPos = .2 + (.075 * y)
        cb.place(rely=relyPos, relx=.5)
        self.documentsChecked.append(cvar)        
    
    def getCheckedItems(self):
        for v in self.documentsChecked:
            if not v.get()=="off":
                print(v.get())
   
    confirmButton = tk.Button(self, text="CONFIRM",command=getCheckedItems(self))
    confirmButton.place(rely=.5, relx=0.5)
```

Comment: `command=getCheckedItems(self)` calls the function *right now* (before the user has even seen the checkboxes, much less had any chance to interact with them).  You want to pass the function itself, rather than call it.  Needing a parameter makes that a bit more complicated - but the function doesn't actually need a parameter: it inherently has access to `self`, due to being nested inside a function that has that name defined.

Comment: You would need `command=lambda: self.getCheckedItems()`.

Comment: lamba does not change a thing sadly. I tried turning the class into a function, making "demarche" a global variable, but I'm really out of ideas about how to do it, I just don't have the skills I guess

Comment: Did you have another instance of `Tk()`?

Comment: Hi yes, this shows up in another Window

Comment: Then the issue is caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Change `Tk()` to `Toplevel()` for all windows other than the main/root window.